# Branch.io links do not work on open alpha release

Tags: android, branch.io

I set up some deep linking to my android application mostly following [Branch.io's github documentation](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking) and the links work fine during development, however they do not work with the open alpha version of the app downloaded from google play. Clicking on a link will still open the desired activity within the app, however it seems like the metadata from Branch is being lost so I cannot populate the activity with the data from the link.

I retrieve the link in the activity with code like this

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.initSession((referringParams, error) -> {
        if (error == null) {
            //disect the params and populate the activity
        }
        else {
            Timber.e("Branch errored with " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }, intent.getData(), this);
```

And the android manifest has branch set up like this (with the correct keys)

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
        android:value="false"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
        android:value="key_live_XXXX"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
        android:value="key_test_XXXX"/>
```

Has anyone else dealt with a problem like this with the link metadata not working on a release build but works on other builds?

Additionally there is also an iOS version of the app that shares a Branch account and has the same problem so I'm assuming it's a configuration problem with Branch

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

It's important to know that every Branch link you create is specific to the Test *OR* the Live environment. This means if you do a Release build and then open a link that was created using the Test key, you won't get any link data. This is by design.

When using Release builds (with the Live Branch key and Test Mode turned off), make sure you're using links that were created using the Live key and you should be all set!

Comment: Thanks for responding! That's good to know, however to my knowledge that's not the problem, both links from the release build and the development build fail to load metadata

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange! Could you please post example links, and console output from both release and development builds so we can debug further?

Comment: It's seeming like the problem was an inconsistency with JsonObject types. Not quite sure why it worked in dev vs release though

Comment: Interesting! Maybe you had debug mode for Branch turned on, and were relying on the extra parameters that returns?